# How to ask for screen recording permission in electron app in Mac OS?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, electron-forge, screen-recording

I am trying to create an app and ask for screen recording permission, but the app asks for permission if i directly execute desktopcapturer.getsources() function with the correct app name added.

Here is an example,

```
const sources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
      types: ["screen"],
      thumbnailSize: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
});
```

I also tried to use below but it was not adding my application name in the system preferences screen recording permissions window,

```
const permissionStatus: string =
      systemPreferences.getMediaAccessStatus("screen");

    // throwing error if no permission given
    if (permissionStatus !== "granted") {
      // Open Screen privacy settings in System Preferences
      shell.openExternal('x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ScreenCapture');
    
      // throw new Error("screen capture, access denied");
      console.log("Permission status ", permissionStatus);
    }
```

I want my app to show the following window when i start it or when my app does not have required permissions
[image: Visual Studio Code asking screen recording permission in mac]

But my app currently just opens the permission window without the name of my app added there as shown below,

[image: screen recording permission screen without app name]